# Windows Services for Linux - Apache?

Tags: apache2, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is there a way to keep my Linux services running after I close the bash prompt?  I had hoped that this would be a little more robust than it actually is.  When I close bash on Windows 10 everything shuts down, which I should have expected of course.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible, but [Microsoft is aware of it and may add that functionality in future](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/13301121-let-bash-continue-running-even-when-the-terminal-h).